# how to compile assembly language in Android?

Tags: android, assembly

Iam incipient to assembly language, can anyone tell how to compile assembly language in Android
I have a Hello world code

```
.text            
.global _start
_start:
    mov r0, #1
    ldr r1, =message
    ldr r2, =len
    mov r7, #4
    swi 0

    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

.data
message:
    .asciz "hello world\n"
len = .-message
```

but i don't know to compile it on Android, can anyone tell

Comment: That is x86-64 code. Your android is likely running ARM, so it won't work.

Comment: Lets start off with the fact that this is clearly x86 assembly, I assume your phone is not x86. There are a lot of other problems as well but thats the first one

Comment: does this edited code run??

Comment: @vkv-onfire it is arm assembly so yes, ill explain a bit more in a bit

Comment: @vkv-onfire You could generally use termux (a terminal emulator on your phone that allows you to use a linux shell on your phone). The binutils package provides you with the `as` and `ld` commands.

Comment: Id advise you continue your research in the termux documentation

Comment: ok, i will try with termux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it can be done using termux. please visit [here](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/ASM)
the answer for this question
i saved my assembly code file as test.s

###### instructions

install binutils 
`pkg install binutils`

`as test.s -o test.o`

`ld test.o -o test`

run your file

`./test`

hello world in other languages and ARM, visit [here](https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world/tree/master/a)

Answer (score 0):

1. install android studio;
2. install NDK in the SDK Manager;
3. open the NDK directory, you can find clang / clang++ compilers for each API,such as API 30;
4. use the clang compiler to compile your assembly file:

aarch64-linux-android33-clang test1.s

```
test1.s:4:9: error: invalid operand for instruction
    mov r0, #1
        ^
test1.s:5:13: error: Only valid when first operand is register
    ldr r1, =message
            ^
test1.s:6:13: error: Only valid when first operand is register
    ldr r2, =len
            ^
test1.s:7:9: error: invalid operand for instruction
    mov r7, #4
        ^
test1.s:8:5: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: sli, sri, wfi?
    swi 0
    ^
test1.s:10:9: error: invalid operand for instruction
    mov r7, #1
        ^
test1.s:11:5: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: sli, sri, wfi?
    swi 0
    ^
```

Comment: The source in the question is for 32-bit ARM.  You're trying to assemble it as AArch64, so of course it fails.  It would be a better example if you either used `arm-linux-...-clang` or used an AArch64 example program.

Comment: You're right. I just found that problem.